# how to solve this error Error " length of 'center' must equal the number of columns of 'x'" while running nnetar

Tags: r

I am not able to run nnetar in r. It is giving error message as

```
Error in scale.default(x, center = center, scale = scale) : 
  length of 'center' must equal the number of columns of 'x'.
```

The used r script is given below.

```r
library(zoo)

Attaching package: ‘zoo’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    as.Date, as.Date.numeric

library(forecast)

Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
  method            from
  as.zoo.data.frame zoo 

library(readxl)
ltcwrm <- read_excel("D:/Dr Malini/caseworm 520/caseworm 520 R/ltcwrm.xlsx")

tsltcwrm=ts(ltcwrm, start=2007, frequency = 52 )

model=nnetar(tsltcwrm)

Error in scale.default(x, center = center, scale = scale) : 
  length of 'center' must equal the number of columns of 'x'
```

How can I solve this problem?